# Issues with horizontal alignment regarding 3 equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

This is my preamble :

```
\documentclass[12pt,thmsa]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
```

First equation issue

```
\begin{flalign}
    {w_1} &= \left\{N_1(-d_+(S_{dt},dt)+N_2(d_+(S_{dt},dt)),-d_+(S_{2dt},dt);-\rho_{12})+N_3(d_+(S_{dt},dt),d_+(S_{2dt},2dt),-d_+(S_{3dt},3dt);\rho_{12},-\rho_{13},-\rho_{23})...\right\},
    \end{flalign}


\begin{flalign}
{w_2} &= \left\{N_1(-d_-(S_{dt},dt)+N_2(d_-(S_{dt},dt)),-d_-(S_{2dt},dt);-\rho_{12})+N_3(d_-(S_{dt},dt),d_-(S_{2dt},2dt),-d_-(S_{3dt},3dt);\rho_{12},-\rho_{13},-\rho_{23})+...\right\},
\end{flalign}
```

This looks like: [image]

My second equation troubling me:

```
\begin{align}
&\varepsilon {B_t} \left\{ {1 - {e^{ - \delta (T - t)}}N( - {d_ + }(\varepsilon {B_t},K,T - t)) - \delta \int\limits_t^T {{e^{ - \delta (s-t)}}N( - {d_ + }(\varepsilon {B_t},{B_s},s - t))\;ds} } \right\} \\
&= K \left\{ {1 - {e^{ - r(T - t)}}N( - {d_ - }(\varepsilon {B_t},K,T - t)) - r\int\limits_t^T {{e^{ - \delta (s-t)}}N( - {d_ - }(\varepsilon {B_t},{B_s},s - t))} {\kern 1pt} \;ds} \right\}.
\end{align}
```

This looks like this: [image]

My third equation:

```
\begin{align}
P_3 = &Xe^{-rT/3}N_1[-d_-(B_{T/3},T/3)]-S_{T/3}N_1[-d_+(B_{T/3},T/3)]\nonumber\\
&+Xe^{-2rT/3}N_2[d_-(B_{T/3},T/3), -d_-(B_{2T/3},2T/3); -1/\sqrt{2}]\nonumber\\
&-S_{T/3, 2T/3}N_2[d_+(B_{T/3}, T/3),-d_+(B_{2T/3},2T/3);-1/\sqrt{2}]\nonumber\\
&+Xe^{-rT}N_3[d_+(B_{T/3},T/3), -d_+(B_{2T/3},2T/3), -d_+(X,T);1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2/3}]\nonumber\\
&-S_{T/3, 2T/3}N_3[d_-(B_{T/3},T/3),d_-(B_{2T/3},2T/3),-d_-(X,T);1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2/3}],
\end{align}
```

This looks like it: [image]

Comment: What's the issue? That those equations are too long?

Comment: they go way passed the equation numbering so  it looks awful

Comment: there is no automatic line breaking, You need to add `\\ ` to break the equations at sensible places. Also please fix the above example so it is a single document people can run to see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose this, based on  `aligned` or `multlined` environments, and the `medium-sized` formulae from `nccmath`. Note you don't have to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,thmsa]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
%\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    w_1 &= \begin{multlined}[t]\Bigl\{N_1(-d_+(S_{dt},dt)+N_2(d_+(S_{dt},dt)),-d_+(S_{2dt},dt);-\rho_{12})\\[-1ex]
    +N_3(d_+(S_{dt},dt),d_+(S_{2dt},2dt),-d_+(S_{3dt},3dt);\rho_{12},-\rho_{13},-\rho_{23})...\Bigr\},\end{multlined}\\
{w_2} &= \begin{multlined}[t]\Bigl\{N_1(-d_-(S_{dt},dt)+N_2(d_-(S_{dt},dt)),-d_-(S_{2dt},dt);-\rho_{12})\\[-1ex]
+ N_3\bigl(d_-(S_{dt},dt),d_-(S_{2dt},2dt),-d_-(S_{3dt},3dt);\rho_{12},-\rho_{13},-\rho_{23}\bigr)+...\Bigr\}\end{multlined}
\end{align}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{align}
\varepsilon {B_t}&\medmath{\Biggl\{ 1 - {e^{ - \delta (T - t)}}N\bigl( - {d_ + }(\varepsilon {B_t},K,T - t)\bigr) - \delta \int\limits_t^T e^{ - \delta (s-t)} N\bigl( -d_{+}(\varepsilon B_t, B_s, s - t)\bigr)\;ds \Biggr\}} \\
= K &\medmath{\Biggl\{ 1 - e^{ - r(T - t)}N\bigl( -d_{-}(\varepsilon B_t, K, T - t)\bigr) - r\int\limits_t^T e^{ - \delta (s-t)}N\bigl(-d_{-} (\varepsilon B_t, B_s, s - t)\bigr) \;ds \Biggr\}}.
\end{align}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P_3 &= {} Xe^{-rT/3}N_1\Bigl[-d_-\Bigl(B_{\tfrac{T}{3}},\mfrac{T}{3}\Bigr)\Bigr]-S_{T/3}N_1\Bigl[-d_+\Bigl(B_{\tfrac{T}{3}},\mfrac{T}{3}\Bigr)\Bigr] \\
&+Xe^{-2rT/3}N_2\Bigl[d_-\Bigl(B_{\tfrac{T}{3}},\mfrac{T}{3}\Bigr), -d_-\Bigl(B_{\tfrac{2T}{3}},\mfrac{2T}{3}\Bigr); -\mfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigr] \\
&-S_{\tfrac{T}{3}, \tfrac{2T}{3}} N_2\Bigl[d_+\Bigl(B_{\tfrac{T}{3}},\mfrac{T}{3}\Bigr),-d_+ \Bigl(B_{\tfrac{2T}{3}},\mfrac{2T}{3}\Bigr);-\mfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigr] \\
&+Xe^{-rT}N_3\Biggl[d_+\Bigl(B_{\tfrac{T}{3}},\mfrac{T}{3}\Bigr), -d_+\Bigl(B_{\tfrac{2T}{3}},\mfrac{2T}{3}\Bigr), -d_+(X,T);\mfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\mfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}},-\sqrt{\mfrac{2}{3}}\Biggr] \\
&-S_{\tfrac{T}{3}, \tfrac{2T}{3}}N_3\Biggl[d_-\Bigl(B_{\tfrac{T}{3}}, \mfrac{T}{3}\Bigr),d_-(B_{2T/3}, 2T/3),-d_-(X,T);\mfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\mfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}},-\sqrt{\mfrac{2}{3}}
\Biggr],
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your equations are a bit too long. I tried and divided them in many rows. It's the best I could do, but please consider defining some longer pieces of the formulas as constants/letters, otherwise it's difficult to keep track and typeset it.

Oh, mind that the `align` environment is meant to align many equations at once with different numbers. What you want is probably `split` or `multline`

```
\documentclass[12pt,thmsa]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[para,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
 w_1 = \{N_1(-d_+(S_{dt},dt)+N_2(d_+(S_{dt},dt)),-d_+(S_{2dt},dt);-\rho_{12})\\
 +N_3(d_+(S_{dt},dt),d_+(S_{2dt},2dt),-d_+(S_{3dt},3dt);\rho_{12},-\rho_{13},-\rho_{23})\ldots\},
\end{multline}
\begin{multline}
{w_2} = \{N_1(-d_-(S_{dt},dt)+N_2(d_-(S_{dt},dt)),-d_-(S_{2dt},dt);-\rho_{12})\\
+N_3(d_-(S_{dt},dt),d_-(S_{2dt},2dt),-d_-(S_{3dt},3dt);\rho_{12},-\rho_{13},-\rho_{23})+\ldots\},
\end{multline}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\varepsilon {B_t} \biggl\{ 1 - {e^{ - \delta (T - t)}}N( - {d_ + }(\varepsilon {B_t},K,T - t)) \\ &{}-\delta \int\limits_t^T {{e^{ - \delta (s-t)}}N( - {d_ + }(\varepsilon {B_t},{B_s},s - t))\;ds}  \biggr\} \\
&= K \biggl\{ 1 - {e^{ - r(T - t)}}N( - {d_ - }(\varepsilon {B_t},K,T - t)) \\
&{}- r\int\limits_t^T {{e^{ - \delta (s-t)}}N( - {d_ - }(\varepsilon {B_t},{B_s},s - t))} {\kern 1pt} \;ds \biggr\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P_3 &= Xe^{-rT/3}N_1[-d_-(B_{T/3},T/3)]-S_{T/3}N_1[-d_+(B_{T/3},T/3)]\\
&{}+Xe^{-2rT/3}N_2[d_-(B_{T/3},T/3), -d_-(B_{2T/3},2T/3); -1/\sqrt{2}]\\
&{}-S_{T/3, 2T/3}N_2[d_+(B_{T/3}, T/3),-d_+(B_{2T/3},2T/3);-1/\sqrt{2}]\\
&{}+Xe^{-rT}N_3[d_+(B_{T/3},T/3), -d_+(B_{2T/3},2T/3),\\
&{} -d_+(X,T);1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2/3}]\\
&{}-S_{T/3, 2T/3}N_3[d_-(B_{T/3},T/3),\\
&d_-(B_{2T/3},2T/3),-d_-(X,T);1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2/3}],\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Moriambar also says your equations are too long. I think you have the same problem in all the equation so I concentrated on the first. Here I first split after the first main `-` but even then the second row was too wide. I have tried to get the contents of paranthesis to align using `\phantom`. Still, it is not really readable, so if it is possible to find shorter expressions it would help.

```
\begin{flalign}
  {w_1} &= \Bigl\{N_1\Bigl(-d_+(S_{dt},dt)+N_2(d_+(S_{dt},dt)),-d_+(S_{2dt},dt);-\rho_{12}\Bigr)\nonumber\\
  &\phantom{{}={}\Bigl\{}
  +N_3\Bigl(d_+(S_{dt},dt),d_+(S_{2dt},2dt),\nonumber\\
  &\phantom{{}={}\Bigl\{{}+N_3\Bigl(}
  -d_+(S_{3dt},3dt);\rho_{12},-\rho_{13},-\rho_{23}\Bigr)\ldots\Bigr\},
\end{flalign}
```

[image]

In cases like this I think you should not use `\left` and `\right`. Instead use e.g. `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` defined in `amsmath` since they don't need to be in pair on the same row. There are many other sizes of them. Second, the alignment `&` should be before the `=` tio get spacing right. You can use `\phantom` to start on other points. Normally I try to have the equation number after the last row, which means supressing the others using `\nonumber`. (There is some other way to do it aslo but I forgot it right now).